# Liquid / Shopify - Variable in CSS

Tags: shopify, liquid

This is my code, I can't get that to return the value from the slider.

```
<div class="slides">

  {% stylesheet %}

  .bg {
    opacity: {{ block.settings.opacity }} ;
  }

  {% endstylesheet %}

  {% for block in section.blocks %}
```

This is .liquid file and the html for the .bg class is in the same file.

```
    {
      "type":      "range",
      "id":        "opacity",
      "min":        0,
      "max":        100,
      "step":       1,
      "label":     "Opacity",
      "default":   50
  },
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

The `{% stylesheet %}` doesn't accept **any** liquid code.

Please refer to: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-use-sections#javascript-and-stylesheet-tags

The important part is here:

> Like the schema tag, javascript and stylesheet tags do not output anything, and **any Liquid inside them will not be executed.**

If you plan to have dynamic styles use the standard `<style>` tag instead of the stylesheet tag.

Comment: Even when i change to <style></style> I still get the same thing.

Comment: @TomHanks well this is not valid `{{ block.settings.opacity }}` you have access to the block object only inside a for loop `{% for block in section.blocks %}{{block.settings.opacity}}{% endfor %}` (or if you target it like so `section.blocks[0]`). You are using standard section without blocks or if you are using blocks, your logic must include the forloop. Without seeing your schema I can't say for certain.